# When stating the time does minutes 分 need to be stated?

Tags: time

For example: It's 6:15.

六時十五分です

Could I just say:

六時十五です

or just:

六時十五

Answer (score 2):

I'm a native Japanese. It depends on the context. When you're talking to a friend/family, you sometimes omit it but rare. Most cases, you add 分 especially if it's in written form or formal conversation. For 六時十五です, you should add 分. It makes sense but it sounds off.